# Windows 7 Crashes using nVidia Driver, works fine in Safe Mode or without video driver

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, crash, nvidia-graphics-card

Until this morning, and for over a year, my computer worked fine. I have an nVidia GTX 465 card running Windows 7 SP-1. Today, after running about thirty seconds, the screen freezes and I have to reboot. The first time this happened, I received a message along the lines "Windows recovered from a video driver crash".

- The computer works fine in Safe Mode.
- If I uninstall the drivers, it works fine in normal mode.
- If I reinstall the drivers (fresh copies from NVidia), it crashes after running for a few seconds.

Prior to the last crash, the last message in my Windows System log is

```
Driver Management concluded the process to install driver 
FileRepository\monitor.inf_amd64_neutral_ab477c4d805d044f\monitor.inf for Device 
Instance ID DISPLAY\HYO049B\5&E3CA944&1&UID3146000 with the following status: 0x0.
```

Any suggestions as to how to fix?

Comment: Have you tried rolling back to an older version of the drivers? It appears there was a driver update just this morning, so there could be a new bug/incompatability that is causing your crashes.

Comment: I've tried both the default Windows driver, dated some time in 2012, and the most recent version. Both have the same problem.

Comment: Sounds like your video adapter might be hosed; if you have access to another Nvidia card to try, I'd recommend doing so, and if that one works with the same drivers with which the GTX 465 doesn't, you've found your culprit.

Comment: @AaronMiller - that's where I'm thinking. I have a second card installed in the computer. I'm going to disable the 465, leave the 210 enabled and connect my monitors to it.

Comment: Sure seems like the culprit. I've rebooted after removing the 465 and the machine appears to be working correctly.

Comment: @BobKaufman perhaps consider answering your question with the solution you found so others can see that answer at a glace if they happen upon the question and have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

The GTX-465 card was indeed bad. Anything more precise than "bad" in our economy of disposable products would be impossible to determine. Removing said card from the computer solved the problem.