# Slightly Corrupt Boot Drive - Can't AUTOCHK because I installed software and need to Restore. Can't Restore because the volume needs to be Autochk'd

Tags: system-restore, chkdsk, filesystem-corruption

After solving [this Video card problem](https://superuser.com/questions/571189/windows-7-crashes-using-nvidia-driver-works-fine-in-safe-mode-or-without-video), on my Windows 7 box, I find myself with a slightly corrupted boot volume. It boots, but wants to run Autochk.

Autochk refuses to run because I've reinstalled my video drivers. It's telling me to go back to a restore point.

System restore tells me that I can't run a system restore because my C: drive is corrupt and I need to run Autochk.

I can deal with ignoring the "please run chkdsk" for all of eternity, however I know well enough that sooner or later, some file will go astray and I'll *have* to run chkdsk.

I've tried rebooting to Safe Mode with Command Prompt, but running CHKDSK /F from the command line gives me a similar "needs system restore" prompt. Running CHKDSK /F from within Windows has predictable non-results.

I've tried running a command-line system integrity check utility and it reports no errors.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the video drivers. Those don't work either.

**EDIT:** I booted from my Windows installation USB key, entered the recovery console, ran a `CHKDSK /F`. It appeared to run successfully. It reported no errors. I rebooted normally and *still* get the message that AUTOCHK cannot run.

**CORRECTION TO EDIT:** I ran `CHKDSK /F` on drive C:, which was *not* the boot drive when booting from my USB key. The correct drive to `CHKDSK` was F:, which when run did report errors that were corrected. A subsequent boot indicates that the problem has been fixed.

Comment: What filesystem issues do you still have? Didn't "CHKDSK /F" fix the reported errors?

Comment: @DonJuandePython - Yes it did. I will clarify in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot your PC from the Windows installation CD and choose R to enter the recovery console. From there you can do a `chkdsk /f`.

If you don't have a Windows CD, you can use [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/).

Comment: I did not suggest to boot into Safe Mode from the current hard disk, but to boot from a Windows Installation CD (or Hiren's Boot CD). If the filesystem is not "mounted" by the installed OS, maybe it will enable him to override the problem and do a chkdsk.

Comment: My bad, downvote removed.

Comment: @DonJuandePython - see edit in OP.